# Graphics g calling

Tags: graphics, java-me, midp, lcdui

In my application I have 1 jar file which I imported in my project. Now I want to access one method of the class (jar file) which contains arguments Graphics(g). I want this method to be accessed in the startApp() of my application, but I can't directly call this method, because Graphics(g) is not supported. Please help me.

Code flow:

```
// 1.class

    public void drawscreen(Graphics g)
    {
    }

// 2.class

    public void startApp()
    {
    1.class.drawscreen()--->here graphics is not supported.
    }
```

Comment: By "is not supported" you mean that you don't have a `Graphics` instance?

Comment: can you please help me what can i do for that?

Answer (score 1):

In `startApp` you have to set some kind of `Canvas` to the `Display`:

`Display.setCurrent(canvas)`.

Your drawing code in your `drawscreen()` method belongs into that canvas. There you can access the `Graphics` context by calling `getGraphics()`.

Honesty you should learn some basics about Java ME if you didn't understand such a basic thing right now.

Comment: I am new to this j2me ..Thanks user714965..Can you please tell me what should i do in my startapp() to call that drawscreen().

Answer (score 1):

You could create a mutable image and pass its graphics to the drawScreen method:

```
    Image img = Image.createImage(100/*width*/, 100/*height*/);
    class1Instance.drawScreen(img.getGraphics());
```